# How to run python scripts one after the other by selecting the tests using easygui?

Tags: python, runtime-error, program-entry-point, easygui, execfile

I am using the following code to select the tests i want to run one after the another.

```
from easygui import *
import sys,os

msg="Select following tests for testing"
title="Test Selector"
choices=["Test_case","Test_case2"]
choice=multchoicebox(msg,title,choices)


print choice
msgbox("You have selected:"+str(choice))
msg="Do you want to continue?"
title="Please confirm"
if ccbox(msg,title):
    pass
else:
    sys.exit(0)

def func():
    for tests in choice:
        print "tests",tests
    return tests
def main():

    execfile('python'+' ' +str( func())+'.py')

main()
```

Now after selecting the tests i want to run those tests one after the other.I am trying to use execfile, but it says

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python Test_case.py'

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: why dont instread exec it you import it? And you should get rid of `"python"+" "`

Comment: tmp=importlib.import_module(tests) if i try to use this it is running only first script,how do I have to make it run for all scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to pass the `'python'` to the name of the file...

```
execfile('Test_case.py')  # willl work
```

or in your case

```
execfile(str( func())+'.py')
```

Look here:

- http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/library/functions.html#execfile

Comment: what if i select more than one tests ,will it try to execute 2 python scripts one after the another?